# Unique page views count (cookie vs. ip address vs. anything else)

Tags: php

I am going to add page views count to my website, where views will be updated in the database. Previously, I have done similar think and I used users' ip address to determine unique views.

Now, I just wonder if I should use cookies instead. I can not understand which one is better. Or should I use both for more strictness?

Somebody with confident mind about this problem, please respond and I will accept your point of view. I just need a little bit more confidence to choose either one or second.

P.S. If you think there is better alternative to those two please be kind to tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happens when 5 PC's connect to your site from the same IP, let's say they are behind a wireless router, is that a good count ? what if the same person who viewed the page had an internet connection with dynamic IP like most broadband internet connections are today

cookies could do the job, but I'm not sure how to tackle this problem and why track at a client level where he navigated, cookies can also be deleted or blocked ...

an easy way would be to use google analytics or google webmaster tools

Comment: I think combining google analytics and cookies is a good idea. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use google analytics
2. Use somekind of http log reader/parser.

Take a look at http://www.phpmyvisites.us/